# How to overwrite an interface config with match option in netplan?

Tags: netplan, systemd-networkd

I am using an Ubuntu 18 on a virtualbox machine and I am trying to overwrite a netplan config related to an interface. There are two config files located in `/etc/netplan/`.

`50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 02:d4:40:b8:a4:a0
            set-name: enp0s3
    version: 2
```

`50-vagrant.yaml`:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: true
    enp0s9:
      dhcp4: true
    enp0s10:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.56.200/24
```

I want to overwrite some configurations in `60-myconfig.yaml`, such that `enp0s8` gets a static IP address and does not use DHCP. However, I prefer to not to use interface name as the key and use `match` instead. But it doesn't work:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    myinterface:
      match:
        name: enp0s8
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.160/24
```

when I change key `myinterface` to `enp0s8` it works properly. I guess netplan does not support overwriting an interface config using `match`. Is it true or I am doing something wrong??

Comment: Through my experimentation, it doesn't appear to support overwriting an interface config using `match`. I can't find anything explicit in the docs that say this, but I tested a couple of different scenarios on Ubuntu 18.04 (netplan 0.99) and got the same results that you did

Comment: On our systems, we just modify the out-of-the-box netplan config files directly. If you absolutely can't (or don't want to) modify `50-vagrant.yaml` directly, then you could create a file `/run/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml` that overrides it. (`/run` is obviously volatile, so to make it "persist" you'd have to create a service that runs on boot and creates this file, either before netplan runs or afterwards and then calling `netplan apply`)